# Two has_many throughs to the same model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :reports
    has_many :social_accounts
    has_one :api_client
    has_many :integrations
    has_many :profiles, through: :integrations

    has_many :tags
    has_many :profiles, through: :tags
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :integration_profiles
    has_many :integrations, through: :integration_profiles

    has_many :users, through: :integrations
    belongs_to :api_client

    has_many :tags
ene
```

At times I want to retrieve all of the user's profiles through the integrations and other times through tags. How?

Answer (score -1):

The answer:

```
has_many :profiles_tagged, through: :tags, source: :profile
```

On the User model